# mongodump, BSONElement: bad type 107

Tags: mongodb, debian, database

Dump the database, there are many errors:

```
Wed Dec 12 02:03:35 Assertion: 10320:BSONElement: bad type 107
0xad0f71 0x67f28b 0x55beab 0x7036ef 0x5635d3 0x566ed0 0x568fd1 0xb42d62 0x5545f2 0x7f0288b39c8d 0x554459
 mongodump(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xad0f71]
 mongodump(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0x9b) [0x67f28b]
 mongodump(_ZNK5mongo11BSONElement4sizeEv+0x1cb) [0x55beab]
 mongodump(_ZNK5mongo7BSONObj10jsonStringENS_16JsonStringFormatEi+0xff) [0x7036ef]
 mongodump(_ZN4Dump17writeMetadataFileESsN5boost11filesystem210basic_pathISsNS1_11path_traitsEEESt3mapISsN5mongo7BSONObjESt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsS7_EEESt8multimapISsS7_S9_SD_E+0x363) [0x5635d3]
 mongodump(_ZN4Dump2goESsN5boost11filesystem210basic_pathISsNS1_11path_traitsEEE+0x1e50) [0x566ed0]
 mongodump(_ZN4Dump3runEv+0x1b61) [0x568fd1]
 mongodump(_ZN5mongo4Tool4mainEiPPc+0x1712) [0xb42d62]
 mongodump(main+0x32) [0x5545f2]
 /lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7f0288b39c8d]
 mongodump(__gxx_personality_v0+0x421) [0x554459]
assertion: 10320 BSONElement: bad type 107
```

Then he took a dump on each collection individually. There was no error.

How, then, to know to what collection this error?
There is an idea why it appeared when dumping the entire database, but when dumping collections do not appear?

Comment: do you have profiling turned on?  could the problem be with system.profile collection?   See possibly related https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7206

Comment: @AsyaKamsky > db.getProfilingLevel()
0

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6877